# Create ListView with Fragment at dynamically in android

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-listfragment

I need to create `ListView` with `Fragment` at my Sample Screen Shot View.

Screen Shots are

[image]

I know it is possible. But how do workout this types of Fragment at dynamically.

I have no idea. In this question and answers are very valuable me. Please give my solutions.

If I have mistaken for my question sorry.

Answer (score 1):

This answer is for those who all searching the answer for same question.
The answer is achieved by FragmentManager and FragmentTransaction with the following syntax.

```
FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
```

then you need to add your fragment to this fragmentTransaction with the following syntax.

```
fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.detailFragment, layout1);
```

And finally you MUST commit your transaction. Otherwise changes will not persist.

```
fragmentTransaction.commit();
```